# How to make my Office 365 Excel Ribbon have small icons like in the picture

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Office 365 subscription and need to start using Excel for a project.  I don't see the Power Query **New Query** option on my installed version, but it is supposed to be present.  The two screen captures show what I see versus what the Microsoft support pages show.

How can I change the size of my Ribbon icons to see if perhaps the Power Query is present but its icons simply do not fit in the space available?

[image: my Excel install ribbon appearance]

[image: Microsoft page Excel ribbon appearance]

Answer (score 1):

The ribbon icons are resized and arranged according to the width of the window. In full screen mode, this maximum width will be determined by the monitor resolution. The icon sizes in the ribbon can not be determined in any Excel settings.

Power Query in Excel 2016 is called Get & Transform and you have it in your ribbon right there. The `Get Data` drop-down in the upper screenshot and the `New Query` drop-down in the lower will open all the Power Query options for new queries.

They changed the words, but if you look closely, you can see that the icon is the same.